# Column borders to fill the entire table even if not enough data

Tags: html, css

Im making a dynamic table and i dont know how many trs i will have:

```html
<div style="height: 20cm">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:0;font-size:12px;width: 100%;text-transform:uppercase;">
    <thead>
      <tr style="font-weight:bold">
        <th style="width:9%;border-bottom:1px solid black;padding:6px;" align="center">cantidad</th>
        <th style="width:12%;border:1px solid black;border-top:0 none;padding:6px;" align="center">codigo</th>
        <th style="width:79%;border-bottom:1px solid black;padding:6px;align: center" align="center">descripcion</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="border-bottom: none;">
      <tr t-foreach="o.pack_operation_ids" t-as="l">
        <td style="border-bottom:0 none;border-right: 1px solid black;border-top: 0 none;padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px">1
        </td>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black;border-top:0 none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px">2
        </td>
        <td style="border-bottom:0 none; border-top: 0 none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px">Description
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Thing is that i need the borders to fill the entire div (to the bottom line), i dont care about the amounts of rows that i will have.

Hope some one can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to actually create the rows

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly the width of columns, you may use background for pseudo element

```
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  content: ''; left: 0; width: 100%;
  background: url('1px-height-with-dots-on-column-positions.png') 0 0 repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a little `jquery or javascript` for this. If you are already familiar with it then it will be great.

Also give `td` **height:30px** and add `border="1"` to table

Check below **snippet**.

```js
$(function(){
var height = $(".main").height();
  height = parseInt(height / 25);
  for(var i = 0; i <= height; i++)
  {
    var newrow = '<tr t-foreach="o.pack_operation_ids" t-as="l"><td style="border-bottom:0 none;border-right: 1px solid black;padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px"></td><td style="border-right:1px solid black; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px"></td><td style="border-bottom:0 none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px"></td></tr>';
    $("table tbody").append(newrow);
  }
});
```

```css
td{
border-bottom:0 none;border-right:0px solid black;border-top: 1 solid black;padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
height:30px;
}

tr{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style="height: 20cm">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:0;font-size:12px;width: 100%;text-transform:uppercase;">
    <thead>
      <tr style="font-weight:bold">
        <th style="width:9%;border-bottom:1px solid black;padding:6px;" align="center">cantidad</th>
        <th style="width:12%;border:1px solid black;border-top:0 none;padding:6px;" align="center">codigo</th>
        <th style="width:79%;border-bottom:1px solid black;padding:6px;align: center" align="center">descripcion</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="border-bottom: none;">
      <tr t-foreach="o.pack_operation_ids" t-as="l">
        <td style="border-bottom:0 none;border-right: 1px solid black;border-top: 0 none;padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px">1
        </td>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black;border-top:0 none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px">2
        </td>
        <td style="border-bottom:0 none; border-top: 0 none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px">Description
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```